# Calculating standard deviation without original measurements

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, standard-deviation

Assume I have the monthly data for the price of items like this:

num_items = [10, 22, 13, 4, 15]

avg_cost = [200, 103, 143, 412, 123]

Now, I do not have the original list of item-wise cost table. From this, I know we can get the overall average, but Is it possible to calculate the overall standard deviation?

Assume I can also add Standard deviation and variance per month, how would I go about calculating the overall std?

Comment: It is absolutely not possible, sorry.

Comment: So you do have the SD of each item group per month? If so, can you edit your question with this information as well.

Comment: @user2974951 I don't have that information right now but assume I can ask for it. And this is just for illustration this is not the actual data. I could get another list std_monthly = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5] etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the months are indexed by $r=1,..m$, each month has $n_r$ observations. Denote the total deviation sum of square $SS_T=\sum_{r=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^{n_r}(y_{ri}-\bar y)^2$, where $\bar y$ is the overall sample mean, it can be proved that $SS_T$ can be decomposed to
$$
{SS}_T = {SS}_A + {SS}_e 
$$
Where $SS_A = \sum_r n_r(\bar y_r - \bar y)^2$ is the **between group deviation sum of square**, $SS_e = \sum_r\sum_i(y_{ri}-\bar y_r)$ is the **within group deviation sum of square**.

With your current information you can only calculate $SS_A$, the between group deviation sum of square.

But if you can get the "variance per month", which is basically a simple transform of within group deviation sum of square $SS_e$, then you can sum $SS_A$ and $SS_e$ to get $SS_T$, and the overall sample variance will be $\frac{SS_T}{\sum_r n_r}$, or $\frac{SS_T}{\sum_r n_r -1}$.